# How to compare two items at the end of the list in a list of list and remove the list if the items are not similar?

Tags: python, list

I got two list of list:

```
a=[[0, 19, 1, 0, 12, 0, 'a'], [19, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 'c'], [1, 2, 0, 0, 2, 0, 'w'], [0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 5, 'Q'], [12, 0, 2, 3, 0, 2, 'front'], [0, 0, 0, 5, 2, 0, 'Z']]
b=[[0, 1, 2, 1, 9, 'a'], [1, 0, 0, 6, 0, 'c'], [2, 0, 0, 15, 2, 'g'], [1, 6, 15, 0, 7, 'w'], [9, 0, 2, 7, 0, 'Q']]
```

If any of the list don't have the same alphabet I want to remove the list from the list of list.Output is:

```
a= [[0, 19, 1, 0, 12, 0, 'a'], [19, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 'c'], [1, 2, 0, 0, 2, 0, 'w'], [0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 5, 'Q']]
b=[[0, 1, 2, 1, 9, 'a'], [1, 0, 0, 6, 0, 'c'], [1, 6, 15, 0, 7, 'w'], [9, 0, 2, 7, 0, 'Q']]
```

I was thinking of using enumerate but I'm not sure how to go about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can firstly find out the common letters in `a` and `b` and then use it as a filter to extract the items that are within the common set from `a` and `b`:

```
common = {x for *_, x in a} & {x for *_, x in b}

a = [x for x in a if x[-1] in common]
b = [x for x in b if x[-1] in common]

a
#[[0, 19, 1, 0, 12, 0, 'a'],
# [19, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 'c'],
# [1, 2, 0, 0, 2, 0, 'w'],
# [0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 5, 'Q']]

b
#[[0, 1, 2, 1, 9, 'a'],
# [1, 0, 0, 6, 0, 'c'],
# [1, 6, 15, 0, 7, 'w'],
# [9, 0, 2, 7, 0, 'Q']]
```

Comment: Although not brought up, how do you solve when all the items are the same but some are in different positions?

Comment: @pylang I don't quite get you. Do you mean duplicated items?

Comment: `[[.., "a"], [.., "b"], [.., "c"]]` vs `[[.., "b"], [.., "a"], [.., "c"]]`

Comment: @pylang Yes OP is not very clear about that part. He might just want to keep both as is.

Comment: Hi again I wonder if there is a way to modify this to store the index of the list that is removed(the lists that are not in common) in both list of list?